# How to make E0 and E1 to act as slaves of X and Y in Marlin firmware?

Tags: marlin

I am currently building a CNC machine and have a plan to use my spare [MKS Base 1.2](http://reprap.org/wiki/MKS_BASE) board. I have successfully activated dual X but when ever I try to activate the dual Y option, it throws a compile error.

BTW, I want to run 5 stepper motors *without* parallel wiring:

- 2 for X;
- 2 for Y, and;
- 1 for Z.

Comment: What is the compile error? Can you edit your question to include the error?

Comment: I've voted to close as the poster hasn't been back since posting this so getting the required information looks unlikely and without that extra information we can not answer the question.